# How to use this simple Plotly?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, plotly

I want to make a simple graphic for my top 5 courses with name and booked times.

Every data is based on different situations.

My html site code:

```
            <tr th:each="m : ${topCourses }">      
                <td th:text="${m.coursName}"></td>  
                <td th:text="${m.bookedTimes}"></td>
            </tr>
```

and I found this plotly code and I'm new to working with JavaScript.

```
var data = [
  {
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

This is an example from plotly.

How can I set my 5 course's name on x, and booked times on y? (this data is automatic changing everyday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" th:with="courseNames=${topCourses.![courseName]},bookedTimes=${topCourses.![bookedTimes]}">
  var courseNames = /*[[${courseNames}]]*/ [];
  var bookedTimes = /*[[${bookedTimes}]]*/ [];

  var data = [{
    x: courseNames,
    y: bookedTimes,
    type: 'bar'
  }];

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
</script>
```

I'm creating 2 temporary `List`s -- `courseNames` and `bookedTimes` (using [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) to create them from the original `List`), and then using [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) to turn them into JavaScript arrays.  Then, just use those variables (instead of hard coded values) and it will create the chart just like you want it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Have lerned a new thing!